# How to add new snippets in Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I know how to create snippets in VS Code but I simultaneously work with Sublime Text. However, I don't know how to create snippets in Sublime Text to python syntax, please help me to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Creating snippets are as easy as VS Code. Just go to **Tools -> Developer -> New Snippet**

You can see xml file like this:

```xml
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.python</scope>
</snippet>
```

1. Edit parameter of  to be a main content and tabTrigger to a
   hint.
2. You can also set a language in  *(python is deafult)*
3. Finally, save this in Sublime folder with **.sublime-snippet**
   extention.
4. Enjoy )

Comment: As an addendum to your answer, as an extra note you can also optionally add in a `<description></description>` pair to set a text description for what the snippet contains.